# Стилизация ul li css

Tags: css

Каким образом без всяких span'ов, div'ов и т.д. сделать кружок сбоку например красным, а текст чёрным?

http://jsfiddle.net/fkkw2Lvr/

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  color: red;
}
ul li {
  color: #000000
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Взгляните на [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306640/setting-bullet-colors-in-ul-li-lists-via-css-without-using-images-or-span-tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте псевдоэлементы 
[:before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before) or [:after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

```css
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul > li{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul > li:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f00;
}
ul > li:hover:before{
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>list  1</li>
    <li>list  2</li>
    <li>list  3</li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rvsoqLox/)

Comment: прекрасно. Спасибо огромное.