# HTML, списки, маркированный список

Tags: html, list

Как сделать квадратные пункты круглыми в маркированном списке?

```html
<h2>Экспорт и импорт Австралии</h2>
    <UL TYPE="disk" >
    <LI> Партнеры по экспорту:
    <UL TYPE="circle">
    <LI> Япония 19%
    <LI> ЕС 14%
    <LI> АСЕАН 12%
    <LI TYPE ="square">
    США 9%
    </LI>
    <LI TYPE ="square">
    Южная Корея
    </LI>
    <LI TYPE ="square">
    Новая Зеландия
    </LI>
    <LI TYPE ="square">
    Китай
    </LI>
    </UL>
    </UL>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/list-style-type изучали?)

Comment: + у вас не закрыты теги li, капсом давно никто теги не пишет

Comment: Нет, не изучал. Сейчас попробую

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, тэг `<li>` закрывать не обязательно.

Comment: Закрывать не обязательно, но желательно. Современные браузеры умеют сами закрывать теги в нужном месте. Только нужное место в понимании браузера может быть иным от того, как задумал сам разработчик. И текущие фрэймворки (например, React) будут заставлять закрывать все теги.

Comment: Я закрыл тэги, но изменить квадратики в списке на черные кружчки "disk"  не смог.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyGGRmW  вот квадратики - так надо ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Стилизация ul li css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430379/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-ul-li-css)

Answer (score 1):

Через css:

```css
.li-disk {
  list-style-type: disc; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Экспорт и импорт Австралии</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Партнеры по экспорту:
    <ul>
      <li>Япония 19%</li>
      <li>ЕС 14%</li>
      <li>АСЕАН 12%</li>
      <li class="li-disk">США 9%</li>
      <li class="li-disk">Южная Корея</li>
      <li class="li-disk">Новая Зеландия</li>
      <li class="li-disk">Китай</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```